# Using LINQ to Entities in Insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, entity

I am refactoring my Database from SQL Queries to Linq.

This function works fine:

```
public void WriteMessageWithSqlServerTimeOld(string message, string connectionString)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder();
            command.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO messages VALUES (GETDATE(), @message);";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", message);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

But i would like to know how you could write this with linq.
My naive attempt looked like this:

```
public void WriteMessageWithSqlServerTimeNew(string message, string connectionString)
{
    var db = new DataContext(connectionString);
    var messages = db.GetTable<MessageEntityClass>();
    var message = new MessageEntityClass()
    {
        Message = message, ServerTime = System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.GetDate()
    };
    messages.InsertOnSubmit(message);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

But this gives me a

> System.NotSupportedException: 'This function can only be called from
>   'LINQ to Entities'.'

Essentially my Question is, how can I call `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.GetDate()` (or any other sql function)
When inserting data into the database?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the basic .NET method, `DateTime.Now`.

It translates to SQL as `GetDate()`.

Your code :

```
var message = new MessageEntityClass()
{
    Message = message, ServerTime = DateTime.Now
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not achieve what i intended. I want the datetime of the sql-server, this gives me the datetime of the client.